Power BI Dax Question - Creating Measure and then another measure on this measure
I have what I hope is a simple use-case, but it's proving to be difficult.
I would like to do the following:
Measure1 = SUM ( Field 1 * Field 2 * 1e6 )  

Please note that fields 1 & 2 are from different tables, and I'm getting an error when trying to run this.
Then , if possible, I want to create a second measure that does this:
Measure 2 =  SUM(If Field4 = "Tiger" then Measure1 else 0 end)

Note Measure 1 in this case should be the result of the calculation up above.
It's funny this feels like this should be quite simple, but I've tried several iterations and cannot seem to get a working calculation.
As a final point, my hope is that slicers selected will also impact these calculations based upon different selections of slicers.
If anyone can help I'd be extremely grateful!

As the error states and is confirmed on DAX guide, SUM only accepts one specific column reference. It cannot do any type of multiplication by other columns.
For your first measure, you can use the following:
Measure1 = 
    SUMX(
        Table,
        Field1 * Field2 * 1e6
    )


It's important to state that the field that comes from another table should be referenced via 'RELATED', like RELATED(OtherTable[Field2] for instance. You basically iterate over your first Table, and 'check' which value for that row can be retrieved in the other table. Keep in mind that you need a many-to-one relationship from your fact table to your dimension table.
The SUMX (or any X function) basically gets a list of values that is returned from the expression, and then it sums it all up together.
If you add any filter context elements to your evaluation context, the 'Table' will be filtered for that filter context.

Measure2 needs more context. Do you plan to put 'Field4' in a table visual or slicer? If you could provide some sample data, I can edit this answer.

Thanks for the quick response.   Upon running the first calculation, I notice that I am getting the same error.   " A single value for column  cannot be determined.  This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation.    I want the sum of the product, not the product of the sum, so not sure if you know how to get past this error.     To your other question, Field4 will not be used in a slicer.


Weird, could you shown in your first post how your sample data and data model (relationships) look like?
The measure actually gives you the sum of the product. It basically iterates over the table row-by-row, does the product of the three values (Field1 * Field2 * 1e6), and then sums up all products.
If field4 will not be used as a slicer, will it be used in a table visual as a column? It will otherwise be impossible for Power BI to know that it should look at Field4, if it is not in the filter context.


I think the issue is that the fields are from different tables in the first measure I'm trying to create.   In your measure syntax, I have to specify the table, and there are multiple tables.   Field 1 is from 1 table and Field2 is from a second table.

As long as there is a relationship between the two, you could use 'RELATED' to get the field (or an equivalent LOOKUP). Again, we need more information about the data model.
